# SpringBatch ItemProcessor: process a List<?> not one Item

Tags: json, spring-batch

I have to modify a process made with SpringBatch, the procedure it's easy. 
Actually, the program reads records from a database and exports the results to XML files (one by each table)

Now, I want to write JSON files instead XML files, I didn't find how to make it possible, but reading and reading I have something close to that I want.

I wrote an `ItemProcessor` class like this

```
@Component("jSONObjectProcessor")
public class JSONObjectProcessor implements ItemProcessor<Object, String> {

    private Gson gson = new Gson();
    private List<Object> array = new ArrayList<Object>();

    @Override
    public String process(Object item) throws Exception {
        array.add(item);
        return gson.toJson(array);
    }
}
```

Obviously, if I have 6 `items`; this going to return 6 `List`, like it does right now

**1st item**

```
[  
   {  
     "number":0,
     "string":"abc",
     "desc":"abcdefg"
   }
]
```

**2nd item**

```
[  
   {  
     "number":0,
     "string":"abc",
     "desc":"abcdefg"
   },
   {  
     "number":1000,
     "string":"xyz",
     "desc":"uvwxyz"
   }
]
//more lists by the total of items
```

To write the files I'm using `org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter` class.

I want to find the way to return all the items in a List and give it JSON form and write this json in the file. I'm in the correct way or there are another, more elegant form. It's possible?

Thanks!

---

**Update**

I have made the changes (thanks @Sanj), but I miss the comma (,) delimiter between each object.

My `ItemWriter` it's defined like this

```
<bean id="itemWriterRegConstantes" scope="step" 
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter">
    <property name="resource" value="#{jobParameters['fileOutput']}" />
    <property name="shouldDeleteIfExists" value="true" />
    <property name="lineAggregator">
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineAggregator">
            <property name="delimiter" value="," />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="footerCallback" ref="headerFooterCallback" />
    <property name="headerCallback" ref="headerFooterCallback" />
</bean>
```

The output file now looks like this

```
[
    {"number":0,"string":"abcd","desc":"efgh"} //no comma
    {"number":1000,"string":"xyz","valor":"xyzw"}
]
```

How add it?

Additionaly, how can I print all the content in a single line? (to minify the content) It's possible?

---

**My Solution**

I had to create my own class (really I made change to the  FlatFileItemWriter SpringBatch class, it's [here](https://github.com/ropherpanama/implementations/tree/master/spring-batch)

Output: a file with an one line JSON array content.
Thanks!

Comment: Are you using ItemWriter to write processed records to a file?

Comment: Yes, I'm using `org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter`

Answer (score 0):

Return single json for every item from ItemProcessor

```
@Component("jSONObjectProcessor")
public class JSONObjectProcessor implements ItemProcessor<Object, String> {

    private Gson gson = new Gson();

    @Override
    public String process(Object item) throws Exception {

        return gson.toJson(item);
    }
}
```

Create header and footer call backs. Basically they will be used to start and close the array respectively.

```
public class JSONHeaderFooterCallBack implements FlatFileHeaderCallback, FlatFileFooterCallback{

    @Override
    public void writeHeader(Writer writer) throws IOException {
        writer.write("[" + System.getProperty("line.separator"));       
    }

    @Override
    public void writeFooter(Writer writer) throws IOException {
        writer.write("]");
    }
}
```

Associate the callbacks with FlatFileItemWriter

```
FlatFileItemWriter<String> writer = new FlatFileItemWriter<String>(); 
//Setting header and footer.
JSONHeaderFooterCallBack headerFooterCallback = new JSONHeaderFooterCallBack();
writer.setHeaderCallback(headerFooterCallback);
writer.setFooterCallback(headerFooterCallback);
writer.setResource(new FileSystemResource(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/output.json"));
```

Now you can use "writer" to write all records as a json array to a file.
**---update--**
Use CustomLineAggregator to append comma at the end of every record:

```
public class CustomLineAggregator<String> implements LineAggregator<String> {

    @Override
    public String aggregate(String item) {
        return item+",";
    }
}
```

Comment: writer.setLineSeparator(",'+System.getProperty("line.separator"))

Comment: The footer and header are in a new line, then this append the comma to the brackets, my config is in xml.

Comment: I had create my own ItemWriter, I'm going to update my answer/question, but your answer was close to solve the problem. Thanks!

Comment: You can extend FlatFileItemWriter. Other option that i have not tried is to have a custom lineaggregator and append comma to the item.